# error in logic calling a PHP function from another PHP function

Tags: php, function, logic

We have a "gotItem" function which, if run on an Item with an "on_hand" value of "1", should also call the "outItem" function.  For some reason, the "gotItem" function is calling the "outItem" function whether or not the "on_hand" value is "1" or "0".  Any ideas why? Code is below

```
function gotItem( $user_item_id, $user_id ) 
{
   $user_item = $this->getUserItem( $user_id, $user_item_id );
   if ( ( ! is_null( $user_item ) ) && ( $user_item['on_hand'] = '1' ) )
   $this->outItem( $user_item_id, $user_id );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=` is used for assignment use `==` for checking

```
  function gotItem( $user_item_id, $user_id ) {
    $user_item = $this->getUserItem( $user_id, $user_item_id );
    if ( ( ! is_null( $user_item ) ) && ( $user_item['on_hand'] == '1' ) )
    $this->outItem( $user_item_id, $user_id );
```

Answer (score 3):

Your comparison is wrong:

```
$user_item['on_hand'] = '1'
```

Should be:

```
$user_item['on_hand'] == '1'
```

The first will always be truthy due to the assignment. Sadly it's a very common mistake, but you could write the condition like:

```
'1' = $user_item['on_hand']
```

That will cause an error because you can not use a literal as left hand expression. An immediate sign that something is wrong in the code :)

Comment: +1 for the solution of a very common and often easily missed by the "author" problem